# GNU Make: delegate target creation to external Makefile

Tags: gnu-make

I am using Makefiles in a project to automate workflows. In order to keep them readable, I have one Makefile in each subdirectory. The structure is like the following:

```
+ a
|- Makefile # with input.txt -> output.txt
|- input.txt
|- output.txt
+ b
|- Makefile # with input.txt -> output.txt
|- input.txt
```

Now, there is a complication: The rule that converts `input.txt` to `output.txt` in `b` also needs `output.txt` from `a`.

I would like to tell my `b/Makefile` to use `a/Makefile` to build `a/output.txt`. Is there any way to do this?

Here is what I tried, and which issues arose:

- Add a rule in `b/Makefile` that does `make -C ../a output.txt`: I can't have a pattern rule using `%.txt: ../a/%.txt` in `b/Makefile` because otherwise it uses this rule to create a recursive definition mess
- Mark `a/output.txt` as `.PHONY` in `b/Makefile`: the target in `b` is rebuilt every time (it should only if `a` rebuilds it)

Comment: Are the filenames *really* the same in both directories? Not using multiple makefiles is probably actually easier here. See the well-known [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf) paper (pdf link) for discussion about that. (That isn't *exactly* what you are doing here but the ideas are the same.)

Comment: No, the file names are not necessarily the same - but they can be. The performance issues outlined in the paper are negligible in my case, my worries are more about read- and maintainability (this is why I prefer multiple Makefiles)

Comment: The performance issues are *by far* not the major thrust of the paper. The major thrust is the splitting of dependency information. Either you duplicate the targets built in each directory in each other directories makefile (e.g. `b/Makefile` contains a target for `../a/output.txt` and `../a/foo.txt` and `../c/something.o` etc.) or you hard-code a build order via manual recursion and lose the only-rebuild-when-necessary properties.

Answer (score 0):

In `a/Makefile`:

```
output.txt: input.txt ../b/output.txt
    cp $< $@

../b/%:
    cd ../b/ && $(MAKE) $*
```

In `b/Makefile`:

```
output.txt: input.txt ../a/output.txt
    cp $< $@

../a/%:
    cd ../a/ && $(MAKE) $*
```

That being said, who don't you have a Makefile at the top level (`..` in this example) that just handles the whole project properly? This would make it a lot more robust, keep you from repeating yourself, and allow parallel execution and other fancy tricks that makes provides.